# How do I use an Existing Database in my Rails Tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, testing, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a postgreSQL database with sample users, content and other data. How can I use it as my test database?

The tests will create new data in it, so I want to be able to easily reset it before each run of tests. Is there an easy way to convert a database into a format that can be used to easily re-create it?

Answer (score 0):

This is the bad Idea to do but you can do this by changing config/database.yml
as

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: development_db 
  pool: 10
  username: username
  password: password
  host: localhost

test 
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: test_db #change this db name to your development_db or whatever you want to use is test environment 
  pool: 10
  username: username
  password: password
  host: localhost
```

Change Test environment database to which you want to use(database with sample users)

**Note: If you want re-use original database again then I would suggest take backup of database with sample users then use this in test environment**

Comment: But how do I automatically reset it every time I run tests?

Answer (score 0):

If your data is not too complex, I would use fixtures for the job. The test database is rolled back after *every* test which can slow down your tests considerably when your test suite grows and your database must be prepopulated before every test.

Comment: Yes, I guess I should use fixtures or factories. I guess I'll need to rewrite the sample data I created with forms.